# It's possible that Team Foundation Server Version Control support external repo like git

Tags: .net, git, version-control, alm

I'm investigate about ALM and Agile ALM, and I did worked with git, mercurial and subversion in the past.

Recently I was working with TFS and I have a question about if TFS suport like in git submodules (or git external for remote repository).

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/) which a package that allows you to use git with TFS repositories. If you install this on your PATH you can clone a TFS repository and then use git to create feature branches and work normally using git strategies. Then instead of pushing / pulling from an origin remote repository you use `git tfs pull` or `git tfs fetch` to pull in new changes from upstream and `git tfs rcheckin` or `git tfs checkin` to commit your work into the TFS repository.

There is even a [plugin](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs-gitextensions-plugin) for [git extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) if you prefer using this GUI to the git command line.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But why would you want to do that?

If the actual issue is that you want to be able to access the source code in a TFS project without VS, then check out http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

GIT and Mercurial are Distributed, TFS is Centralized :(
Maybe with [the git-tfs project](http://www.drrandom.org/post/2011/11/16/Grappling-with-multiple-remotes-in-git-tfs.aspx) :)

Regards.